# GIS Layers into Google Maps Search

Tags: mapping, gis

I'm trying to create a website where users enter their address and the website returns who their local representatives are.

An example:
https://www.sec.state.ma.us/WhereDoIVoteMA/

I'm essentially trying to recreate the website above, but add additional items like pictures etc. I'm very much a beginner so I'm not really sure where to get started. I know MA provides GIS data and Data Layers, however I'm not sure if I need these for the website.

Appreciate any help anyone can provide.

I created a website that can reference an individual town, but the tricky part is many towns have multiple districts. I want the website to determine which district they live in.